# Any ways to speed up like 'foo%' queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have many queries like

```
select * from table where (upper (column1) like 'FOO%') 
                    and (upper (column2) like 'BAR%')
                    and (upper (column3) like 'XYZ%')
```

And suach an index:

```
create index on table (upper(column1::text), upper(column2::text), upper(column3::text));
```

But for some reason queries are pretty slow and explain operator shows that it doesn't use any index scan, just simple sec scan. I've read that B-tree index type is the best for queries like mine with anchor in the end of the constant.
Any ideas why this happen? May be something wrong with my index creation command?

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need three indexes:

```
/* "text_pattern_ops" makes the index usable for LIKE */
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (column1 text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (column2 text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (column3 text_pattern_ops);
```

PostgreSQL will scan the index or the indexes for the `WHERE` conditions that promise to significantly reduce the number of rows. If it scans several indexes, it can combine the result. If one of these `WHERE` conditions is never selective, you can omit the corresponding index, since it won't be used.

You won't be able to cover that query with a single index.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your indexes as soon as i get access to db)

Comment: Ok, unfortunately this didn't work for me, postgress still use seq scan

Comment: Unless you add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query to the question, I cannot analyze this further....

Answer (score 0):

Well the use of the `UPPER` function on the three columns basically precludes any chance of an index being used.  However, if you could ensure that you only store uppercase values in the three columns, then you could add an index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (column1, column2, column3);
```

You would then use this version of your query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE column1 LIKE 'FOO%' AND column2 LIKE 'BAR%' AND column3 LIKE 'XYZ%';
```

The reason this index would work is that your `LIKE` expressions are substrings starting from the very beginning of the column values.  As a result, a B-tree index can be used to search for these starting substrings.

Comment: Sadly, values in all three columns can be in uppercase or in lowercase or in any other case, but search should be case insensitive.

Comment: Then use your current index with the query version in my answer.  If you can maintain an uppercase index, then my query should be fast.

Comment: I can't use such query withoud using upper function on value in column because then i will select only rows that already in upper case.